# Proving a corollary to Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0$ be a point in an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Let $f,g:U \to \Delta(0,1)$ where $g$ is a bijection such that $g(z_0)=0$ and $g'(z_0)\neq 0$. Suppose that $f(z_0)=0$, then $|f'(z_0)|\leq |g'(z_0)|$

I am not even sure how to start this.  I was assuming Schwarz lemma.

Comment: What is $\Delta (0,1)$. What is $\phi$ and what is the use of $g$? Is there any relation between $f,g,\phi$?

Comment: $\phi$ was just a mistake.  $\Delta(0,1)$ is a disk of radius 1 centered at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the map $f\circ g^{-1}\colon \Delta(0,1)\to \Delta(0,1)$.

Comment: This allows us to use Schwarz's inequality.  But how does that show the inequality that involve the derivatives?

Comment: It is just the consequence of Schwarz lemma. Did you verified it?

Comment: Yes, I just don't see the relationship between the derivatives.

Comment: @MehulJwe: The Schwarz lemma gives you that if $h\colon \Delta(0,1)\to \Delta(0,1)$ is a holomorphic map with $h(0) = 0$, then $|h'(0)|\leq 1$. So now try to apply that with $h = f\circ g^{-1}$. In this case, can you compute $|h'(0)|$? You should be able to do it with the chain rule....

Comment: We have $h'(0)=f'(g^{-1}(0))g^{-1}(0)$.  Then $|f'(g^{-1}(0))g^{-1}(0)|\leq 1$.  That's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: I think you mean $h'(0) = f'(g^{-1}(0))\cdot (g^{-1})'(0)$. Now, you know that $g^{-1}(0) = z_0$ because that's given in the problem, so the only thing left to do is to compute what $(g^{-1})'(0)$ is. I claim that $(g^{-1})'(0) = 1/g'(z_0)$. To prove this, I suggest taking the derivative of $g\circ g^{-1} \equiv z$ at the point $z = 0$.